# date comparison in java for date of birth

Tags: java, date

I have a date in `String` format as `String dob="02/26/2013";` which is in the format "mm/dd/yyy". Its a date of birth and I want to check that this dob should be less than today's date. How to check that?

Here is my code:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String date1 = format1.format(date);
    System.out.println(date1);
    String date2 = "2013/02/26";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
    Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date2);
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

but `convertedDate` is printing as `Sat Jan 26 00:02:00 IST 2013`

Comment: What have you tried? (I'd recommend using Joda Time rather than java.util.Calendar / java.util.Date, by the way.)

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 
  Date date = cal.getTime();             
  SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
  String date1 = format1.format(date);            
     System.out.println(date1);
  String date2 = "2013/02/26";
 
     
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd"); 
     Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date2); 
System.out.println(convertedDate);

Comment: instead of putting code in comment, edit your question.

Comment: but convertedDate is printing as Sat Jan 26 00:02:00 IST 2013

Comment: @JonSkeet, why Joda is recommended?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov - Because it allows an easier interface to convert a Date into a printed string.  You never even attempt to compare the two Dates why is that exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String dob="02/27/2013";
    Date today = new Date();

    try {
        Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(dob);

        if (dobDate.compareTo(today) <= 0) {
            //before or equals today
            System.out.println("before");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //handle exception
    }
```

Comment: hey its working fine but for today"s date also its goin in if loop the dob should not be even today's date

Comment: If you're checking for birthday, you might not get what you want because 29/11/1992 < 29/11/2015 even though it's a birthday.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        Date date1 = sdf.parse("02/26/2013");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse(strDate);

     if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
        }else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
            System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
        }
```

Comment: i tried that code but m getting error convert date2 into string at line 3

Comment: check nikolay answer below its much shorter

Answer (score 1):

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");` is wrong. `mm` is minutes, which is why you get 2 minutes after midnight Jan 26. Change `mm` to `MM`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Joda time, you could also try to convert the String into a Calendar object and use the before or after methods as needed.. For more help please read the Javadoc for the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) classes.

Comment: moreover what if locale is not english

Comment: @user2025528 - Why would the locale matter in a case like this?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
String yourdate = "02/26/2013";
Date toDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(yourdate);
long toDateAsTimestamp = toDate.getTime();
long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
long getRidOfTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
long toDateAsTimestampWithoutTime = toDateAsTimestamp / getRidOfTime;
long currentTimestampWithoutTime = currentTimestamp / getRidOfTime;

if (toDateAsTimestampWithoutTime <= currentTimestampWithoutTime) {
    System.out.println("Display error.");
} else {
    System.out.println("All ok");
}
```

Comment: its printing display error for even "02/27/2013" but for "02/28/2013" its printing all ok